# How make motion blur without Post Process in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm watching thesis about motion blur in OpenGL, then use Current position and Previous position but I don't know how to get Previous position in unity shader code. please Help me  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB2w1.png)

How to get Previous Position in Unity vertex & fragment shader code

Comment: There's no "previous" coord. Coords are the same on every frame. The location of objects is determined by model-view-projection matrices that you pass as uniforms. In other words, `float4 Pprev = mul(prevModelView, in.coord)`

Comment: Um, Can you give me some hint, How to make motion blur in Unity